Spring data one-to-many association is empty after save
Having the following entities:
TagMembershipType
public enum TagMembershipType {
    USER, OWNER
}

Tags
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)
public class TagInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @ToString.Include
    private Integer tagId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tag_membership",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagId", referencedColumnName = "tagId")
    )
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "member_type = 0")
    private List<TagMembership> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tag_membership",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tagId", referencedColumnName = "tagId")
    )
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "member_type = 1")
    private List<TagMembership> owners = new ArrayList<>();
}

TagMembership
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"tag", "member"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"tag", "member"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag_membership")
public class TagMembership {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tagId")
    private Tag tag;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "memberId")
    private Member member;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private TagMembershipType memberType;
}

Member
@Data
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private long memberIdId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;
}

Entity creation
...

final Tag tag = modelMapper.map(tagDTO, Tag.class);
final Tag dbTag = tagRepository.save(tag);

final Member member = modelMapper.map(memberDTO, Member.class);
final Member dbMember = memberRepository.save(member);

TagMembership tagMembership = new TagMembership();
tagMembership.setTag(dbTag);
tagMembership.setMember(dbMember);
tagMembership.setMemberType(TagMembershipType.USER);

tagMembershipRepository.save(tagMembership);

tagMembership = new TagMembership();
tagMembership.setTag(dbTag);
tagMembership.setMember(dbMember);
tagMembership.setMemberType(TagMembershipType.OWNER);

tagMembershipRepository.save(tagMembership);

final List<TagMembership> owners = dbTag.getOwners(); // empty - unexpected!
final List<TagMembership> users = dbTag.getUsers(); // empty - unexpected!

The question is, why owners and users of dbTag are empty?
